# Is this a Dracaena reflexa?

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, dracaena

I struggle to identify this plant. I have searched for similar leaves but could not find a definitive answer yet.

Some details about the plant:

- age: about seven years
- height: 80 inches / 2 m (as seen on the photo)
- it won't stop growing :)

[image: full height]
[image: leaf]

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it's Dracaena deremensis, most likely the variety 'rhoersii' - it looks exactly like my own one,except yours is more than twice the height of mine and the lower part of the stem is bare of leaves. Often described as D. warneckii rather than D deremensis 'warneckii' or as Dracaena 'Janet Craig' - I've had no luck finding an image of an actual Dracaena deremensis grown as a houseplant on line, closest I can find is here, but it doesn't have the same growth habit as yours and mine https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/all/dracaena-deremensis/

I'm considering uploading a photo of my own one instead, but discovered my camera's not functioning currently... listed correctly in a book called The Houseplant Expert by D.G. Hessayon, with good images.

UPDATED ANSWER

You're right, I don't mean D. 'rhoersii' (those yellow stripes looked white under low electric light in my houseplant book, my apologies) - I had a look at D. 'kanzi' as you suggested and yes, could be that. or D. deremensis 'warneckii'

Comment: Are you sure about the variety 'rhoersii'? I've looked for this variety and according to the book *'HITS: House, Interior, Tropical, and Succulent Plants: Genera D to E'* 'rhoersii' has yellow margined leaves. My plant's leaves don't contain any yellow. What do you think about the variety 'Kanzi'? As far as I can tell it seems more like the plant on the photo above ("Dracaena deremensis 'Kanzi' lc: with wide white stripes, usually 2 distinct submarginal bands. (...)")

Comment: You're right, its not rhoersii, that's what I get for only having a low lamp on when I checked the pics, sorry about that! Might be Dracaena deremensis warneckii in fact, or 'Kanzi'... I'll update the answer